# If two object refers to each other, is that a sign of bad code?

Tags: php

given this code:

```
class EmailHander
{
    public $mailer;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    }

    public function getEmail ($name)
    {
        return new EmailTemplate ($name, $this);
    }
}

class EmailTemplate
{
    public $body, $subject, $handler;

    public __construct ($name, EmailHander $handler)
    {
        require ($name.'.html');
        $this->handler = $handler;
    }

    public function send ($target)
    {
        $this->handler->mailer->send ($target, ......);
    }
}
```

there is an `EmailHandler` which deals with the mailer, and many `EmailTemplates` which represents the emails. So,

```
$handler = new EmailHandler();
$email = $hander->getEmail ('subScribe');
$email->send('x@y.com');
```

but this is might bad. The `EmailHandler` produces an `EmailTemplate`. But `EmailTemplate` refers to `EmailHandler`, so this is a circular thing, is that good or bad?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's good, or whether it's bad?

Comment: whether its bad? Somehow I feel its not OK, but dunno why...

Comment: Your question's concluding words are "isnt that good?"

Comment: Didn't need to say it twice! :)

Comment: yes I needed, comments cannot be less than 15 characters.

Comment: I think the purpose of that restriction is to encourage you to write a full English sentence, not to write the single-word comment twice.

Comment: The only problem I see in your code is that you frequently misspell `handler`, leaving out the `l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no circular dependency in this code. There is a one-way dependency from an email to its handler; doesn't matter that the handler set up the dependency.